# Unsupported Operand Type + More Issues (most likely)

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop

I am trying to make a lossy text compression program, but it gives me an error on line 7 for `unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'`. What I am trying to do is remove all vowels from the text except for ones that are the first letter of a word.

```
text = str(input('Message: '))
text = (' ' + text)
listtext = list(text)

for i in listtext[1:]: #trying to start for loop at index 1, i.e. skipping 
the first index, does this work?
  if i == 'a' or i == 'e' or i == 'i' or i == 'o' or i == 'u': 
    if listtext[i-1] == ' ': #line 7
      i = i + 1
    else:
      listtext[i] = ''
      i = i + 1

text = "".join(text_list)
print(text)
```

Comment: What are you expecting `i-1` to do? As the error notes, `i` is a String, not a number.

Comment: i isnt an index number, its one character in the list at a time, as you seem to know from doing things like `i == a`. so, `listtext[i-1]` is invalid.

Comment: The intention of i-1 is to check to see if the index before it is a space, therefore determining whether the current index is the first letter of a word.

Comment: How would i check to see if there is a certain string in the previous index?

Comment: check out enumerate in python.

Comment: You are confusing the index of an item in a list with the item itself. In `['a', 'b', 'c']` the letter b has an index of 1 but it's still 'b'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem can be easily solved with RegEx. Try this:

```
import re

text = ' ' + input('Message: ')
text = re.sub(r'(?<! )[aeiouAEIOU]', '', text)[1:]
print(text)
```

Example:

```
Message: Aaaa. Foo bar baz. An apple.
A. F br bz. An appl.
```

Comment: This is awesome, but can you explain to me what's going on in line 4? I've obviously never used RegEx, I just want to know what it does.

Comment: The second section (`[aeiouAEIOU]`) looks for any character matching any of the enclosed characters. The first section (`(?<! )`) makes sure there's no space behind any matching characters. Then, substitute all matches with an empty string.